# Can't figure out how to reuse terraform provisioners

Tags: terraform

I've created some (remote-exec and file) provisioners to bootstrap (GCP) VMs that I'm creating that I want to apply to all my VMs, but I can't seem to figure out how to reuse them...?

Modules seem like the obvious answer, but creating a module to create the VMs means I'd need to make input vars for everything that I'd want to configure on each of the VMs specifically...

Reusing the snippets with the provisioners doesn't seem possible though?

Comment: Can you share your existing Terraform code and then also highlight how that doesn't do what you want it to do?

Answer (score 0):

Terraform's Provisioner feature is intended as a sort of "last resort" for situations where there is no alternative but to SSH into a machine and run commands on it remotely, but generally we should explore other options first.

The ideal case is to design your machine images so that they are already correctly configured for what they need to do and so they can immediately start doing that work on boot. If you use [HashiCorp Packer](https://packer.io/) then you can potentially run very similar steps at image build time to what you might've otherwise run at Terraform create time with provisioners, perhaps allowing you to easily adapt the work you already did.

If they need some configuration parameters from Terraform in order to start their work, you can use features like the GCP instance `metadata` argument to pass in those values so that the software in the image can access it as soon as the system boots.

A second-best sort of option is to use features like [GCP startup scripts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) to pass the script to run via `metadata` so that again it's available immediately on boot, without the need to wait for the SSH server to start up and become available.

In both of these cases, the idea is to rely on features provided by the compute platform to treat the compute instances as a sort of "appliance", so Terraform (and you) can think of them as being similar to a resource modelling a hosted service. Terraform is concerned only with starting and stopping this black box infrastructure and wiring it in with other infrastructure, and the instance handles its implementation details itself. For use-cases where horizontal scaling is appropriate, this also plays nicely with managed autoscaling functionality like [`google_compute_instance_group`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/d/google_compute_instance_group.html), since new instances can be started by that system rather than directly by Terraform.

---

Because Provisioners are designed as a last-resort for when approaches like the above are not available, their design does not include any means for general reuse. It's expected that each provisioner will be a tailored solution to a specific problem inline in the resource it relates to, not something you use systematically across many separate callers.

With that said, if you are using `file` and `remote-exec` in particular you can get partway there by factoring out the specific file to be uploaded and the remote command to execute, in which case your resource blocks will contain just the declaration boilerplate while avoiding repetition of the implementation details. For example, if you had a module that exported outputs `local_file_path`, `remote_file_path`, and `remote_commands` you could write something like this:

```
module "provisioner_info" {
  source = "./modules/provisioner-info"
}

resource "any" "example" {
  # ...

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = module.provisioner_info.local_file_path
    destination = module.provisioner_info.remote_file_path
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = module.provisioner_info.remote_commands
  }
}
```

That is the limit for factoring out provisioner details in current versions of Terraform.